# What is the smallest encoding?

Tags: mysql, character-set

I am now using `latin1` (`CHAR 10` column type) and I was wondering if there is more efficient character-set to store password hash consisting of `a-z0-9` characters.

Comment: I think a 5-bit encoding like Baudot would work, but I don't think MySQL supports it: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baudot_code encodings supported: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-j-reference-charsets.html

Comment: Why isn't the hash `a-f0-9` ? then you would be able to save it as binary blob of the bytes.